# Find specific lower or uppercase

Tags: excel, vba, search, find

```
If ws.cell(a,7) = “N” then ......
```

My question is I am able to find those character with “N” but when I fill “n” at column the result can’t display but only just those “N” only , how can I add so be it “N” or “n” it will display result ...

Comment: Note that you need to use the correct qoutes in VBA because these fancy quotes `“N”` are not allowed and you need to use the normal ones `"N"`!

Answer (score 2):

You can add UCase so that either "N" or "n" will be evaluaded as "N":

```
If UCase(ws.cell(a, 7)) = "N" Then
    MsgBox "This is N or n"
End If
```

Comment: No problem - verify and if the answer is correct then please approve it. Thanks :)